# parsing integer value

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I have an xml document with the structure like this

```
<id>some number like 456<\id>
<name>some name like string<\name>
```

So I parse the document with NSXMLParser and put the result in to an array ogf objects with the structure like the xml entity.

But when I try to parse the id like a NSInteger it can not do this I parsing it like NSNumber.

After the parsing is finished and I have the contents of my xml doc in to an array I print the array values and the number the id entry has a totally different values than this in to the xml doc.

Why is happening like this I do not know? Any help will be useful.

Comment: could we see the code please? Also what is the value of <id> ? Is it numeric or alphanumeric?

Comment: I do it it works now teh problem was the space in the id value which is nmber .

Answer (score 0):

is that what the xml looks like? beacuse the <\id> should be

Second option how are you parsing the id value should be something like

```
[Array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[string intvalue]]];
```

That said i need to see the code and output to properly answer